# lookup a dictionary within a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like below :

```
df1

|id|   domains| name|
| 1|      life|  xyz|
| 2|      life|  hyu|
| 3|vkontakete|  jik|
```

And a dictionary :

```
domain_dict = { "tassagency": "TACC",
                "life": "LIFE.ru",
                "ria": "RIA | Taza", 
                "nws_ru" : "NEWS.ru | Новости",
                "mash" :"Mash | Мэш"}
```

I want to get the values from domain_dict by matching the keys from dictionary in the domains column of df1 and put it in new column in df1, if the domains in df1 doesn't match any key in dictionary, we will keep the same in df1 as seen in expected output in 3rd record.

I tried below approach :

```
df1["vk_dom"] = np.nan

for i in df1.index:
    for i,(k, v) in enumerate(domain_dict.items()):
        if k == (df1['domains'][i]):
            df1["vk_dom"][i] = v
        else:
            df1["vk_dom"][i] = df1['domains'][i]
```

how can I get below expected output :

```
|id|   domains| name|     vk_dom|
| 1|      life|  xyz|    LIFE.ru|
| 2|      life|  hyu|    LIFE.ru|
| 3|vkontakete|  jik| vkontakete|
```

Comment: Simple `replace`: `df['vk_dom'] = df['domains'].replace(domain_dict)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the domains column to the values in the domain_dict.

```py
df1["vk_dom"] = df1["domains"].map(domain_dict).fillna(df1["domains"])
print(df1)
```

---

```
   id     domains name      vk_dom
0   1        life  xyz     LIFE.ru
1   2        life  hyu     LIFE.ru
2   3  vkontakete  jik  vkontakete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

domain_dict = {
    "tassagency": "TACC",
    "life": "LIFE.ru",
    "ria": "RIA | Taza",
    "nws_ru" : "NEWS.ru | Новости",
    "mash" :"Mash | Мэш"
}

df2 = pd.Series(domain_dict).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['domains', 'vk_dom']


df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['domains'], how = 'left')

df1.vk_dom = df1.vk_dom.combine_first(df1.domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataFrame` from the domain_dict -> `merge` it with your df1 using `left join` -> fill NaNs with the values from domain column:

```
domain_dict = {
            "tassagency": "TACC",
            "life": "LIFE.ru",
            "ria": "RIA | Taza",
            "nws_ru" : "NEWS.ru | Новости",
            "mash" :"Mash | Мэш"
        }
        
domain_df = pd.DataFrame(domain_dict.items(), columns=['domains', 'vk_dom'])
result = df1.merge(domain_df, how='left', on='domains')
result.loc[result['vk_dom'].isnull(), 'vk_dom'] = result['domains']
```

This will give you the following DataFrame named result:

```
    id  domains name    vk_dom
0   1   life    xyz LIFE.ru
1   2   life    hyu LIFE.ru
2   3   vkontakete  jik vkontakete
```